# Adding row to a table without messing Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am looking for some workaround for my Google Sheets I share with my co-workers.
I have a data set in Sheet1 (col's A to E), which contains data including empty rows. By using Arrayformula I am pulling data from Sheet1 to Sheet2, only if they meet specific conditions (A="1" and B="DFAS"). Then I apply filter to hide empty rows.

Here comes my problem: next to data pulled by Arrayformula I want to be able to input data (in col's F and G) which correspnds to specific rows from Sheet1, and it has to stay there. The problem is that if I add new rows in Sheet1 the result of Arrayformula shifts but col's F and G in Sheet2 stays as they were, and it all gets messed up.
Do you have any idea how to work around it?
I am sharing the google sheets file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MvuEDqidLPKfSHATYQ68X9pJFhixTg9TJrq4F3crgUs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet is private.

Comment: Right, now corrected

Comment: Could you share what will be the expected result?

Comment: Now in Sheet2 is the effect I get, and in Sheet3 is the effect I want.

Comment: Usually this task is solved (more or less) using Google App Script. Or you can get the rows from the 1st sheet by using data validation drop down (introduce some id for that) and then pulling every column corresponding to the row of the id by `ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(...))`.

Comment: After thinking this through, perhaps I should ask different question: why data in Sheet2 in columns F and G stay in the same row, despite adding a new row in Sheet1 and as a result of Arrayformula in Sheet2 as well. I want colum F and G shift as well, that would solve my issue.